# Passing object from one scene to next

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass an object in Swift from one scene to the next, and I'm getting an error with the code below saying:

> Cannot invoke indexPathForSelectedRow with no arguments.

Is this a new requirement?

It seems to me the code below should work, but I'm confused as to why it isn't.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var propertyArray: [Property] = [Property]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setUpProperties()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func setUpProperties() {

    var property1 = Property(cardImage: "image1.png", name: "Name1", location: "Hollywood")
    var property2 = Property(cardImage: "image2.png", name: "Name2", location: "Astoria")
    var property3 = Property(cardImage: "image3.png", name: "Name3", location: "Ft. Greene")

    propertyArray.append(property1)
    propertyArray.append(property2)
    propertyArray.append(property3)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return propertyArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedCell") as! CustomCell

    let property = propertyArray[indexPath.row]

    println(property.name + " " + property.location)

    cell.setProperty(property.cardImage, name: property.name, location: property.location)

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        var detailPage = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

        let selectedProperty = propertyArray[indexPath.row]
        detailPage.currentProperty = selectedProperty

        }

        }


    }
```

}

Comment: It's a weird error since nothing seems to be wrong there. How is `tableView` definition?

Comment: Thanks for looking, @ClaudioRedi... I've added the tableview definition in the original post above.

Comment: No, he means what is `self.tableView`. Is this code running in a UITableViewController?

Comment: Have you subclassed UITableView and written your own `indexPathForSelectedRow` function or something weird like that?

Comment: Have you tried quitting, cleaning the caches, and restarting? Sometimes Xcode just loses its mind and needs to be slapped on the head.

Comment: Thanks, @matt, will try that. The code is in a UITableView within a UIViewController (see above... I added all the code from this class. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is a little odd that this is a UIViewController subclass and not a UITableViewController subclass but I still don't see why your code would not compile.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried clearing out all the files, and quitting/restarting... still no dice. Maddening! Thanks for trying. No idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Sorry--didn't want to trouble anyone further. I understand that accepting an answer that didn't (yet) work might be misleading. I reversed it.

Comment: We need to fix this! Can you post the whole project somewhere so I can download it and see for myself? I'm sure this will turn out to have an easy solution but we are not getting at it somehow.

Comment: Wow--thanks so much! I posted the project here: http://www.telodesign.com/Feed.zip

Comment: Well, we needn't have gone to all that trouble; I should have seen it from the code you posted! But anyway, I solved it; see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in this line:

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
```

you have not correctly used the name of your view controller's property. Its name is `myTableView`. So change it to this:

```
if let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Thanks for your help, @matt. My code's still not compiling, but I'll keep trying this, and am glad to know about the glitch/cache-clearing.

Comment: @matt--thank you so much for taking the time to do this. i really appreciate it, and it helped me out of a bind i was stuck in for many hours. major karma points, sir!

Comment: It's amazing how blind one can be to this sort of thing. You didn't see it, I didn't see it! The problem is, of course, that Swift's misleading error message kept us looking in the wrong place. It had no idea what `self.tableView` was, so why didn't it just say so?? Bad Swift! :)